# Transposing Undefined Number of Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, dynamic, pivot, transpose

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
Member, Contract_Start, Contract_End  
1,  1/1/2011,   12/30/2011  
1,  1/1/2012,   12/30/2012  
1,  1/1/2013,   12/30/2013  
2,  7/1/2012,   12/30/2012  
2,  1/1/2013,   12/30/2013
```

Members could have as few as 1 contract and there is no upper limit on number of contracts.
I'd like to switch the table to look like below:

```
Member, Contract_Start1, Contract_End1, Contract_Start2, Contract_End2.....   
1, 1/1/2011, 12/30/2011, 1/1/2012, 12/30/2012  
2, 7/1/2012, 12/30/2012, 1/1/2013, 12/30/2013
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Ideally do it in your reporting layer, or consuming application. SQL is not good at dealing with records of varying length.

Comment: you will have to prepare Dynamic SQL that supplies Select and PIVOT column list dynamically. just curious, what is basic need to transpose data such way. because when you looking at my Transposed Data for Member-1 there may be 10 contract date and for member-2 may be just 1. so 9 columns will have null.

Comment: Anup, My basic need for this is to identify gaps in contract coverage for a member.

Comment: What database? Postgres? Oracle? SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

I have used such solution and would advise not to go this path because maintenance/debugging of such dynamic sql becomes to hard over long time.

you can try the demo [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/99bd1/1)

```
    IF object_id('Test_Transpose') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE Test_Transpose
    GO
    CREATE TABLE Test_Transpose
    (
        memberID    INT NOT NULL
        ,csdate     datetime2(2) NULL
        ,cedate     datetime2(2) NULL
    )
    INSERT INTO Test_Transpose (memberid,csdate,cedate)
                SELECT 1,'1/1/2001','1/1/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'1/2/2001','1/2/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'1/3/2001','1/2/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'1/4/2001','1/2/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 1,'1/5/2001','1/2/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2,'1/2/2001','1/2/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 2,'1/3/2001','1/3/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3,'1/2/2001','1/2/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3,'1/3/2001','1/3/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 3,'1/4/2001','1/4/2001'
    UNION ALL   SELECT 4,'1/2/2001','1/2/2001'


    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@Startdate_SelectColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@EndDate_SelectColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@Final_SelectColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@PivotINColumnList NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
            ,@MaxContractDateCount INT=1

    SELECT TOP 1 @MaxContractDateCount = COUNT(1)
    FROM Test_Transpose
    GROUP BY memberid
    ORDER BY COUNT(1) desc


    WHILE @MaxContractDateCount > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Startdate_SelectColumnList =    N'['+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)+N'] AS '
                                                +N'StartDate'+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)
                                                +CASE WHEN @Startdate_SelectColumnList=N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END
                                                +@Startdate_SelectColumnList

        SELECT @Enddate_SelectColumnList =      N'['+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)+N'] AS '
                                                +N'EndDate'+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)
                                                +CASE WHEN @Enddate_SelectColumnList=N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END
                                                +@Enddate_SelectColumnList

        SELECT @Final_SelectColumnList =        N'StartDate'+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)+N','
                                                +N'EndDate'+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)
                                                +CASE WHEN @Final_SelectColumnList=N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END
                                                +@Final_SelectColumnList

        SELECT @PivotINColumnList =             N'['+CAST(@MaxContractDateCount AS sysname)+N']'
                                                +CASE WHEN @PivotINColumnList=N'' THEN N'' ELSE N',' END
                                                +@PivotINColumnList

        SET @MaxContractDateCount=@MaxContractDateCount-1
    END

    --debug stmt
    --SELECT @Startdate_SelectColumnList,@Enddate_SelectColumnList,@Final_SelectColumnList,@PivotINColumnList

    SET @SQL = N'
                SELECT q1.memberid,'
                +@Final_SelectColumnList
                +N'
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT  memberid,'
                +@Startdate_SelectColumnList
                +N'
                    FROM
                    (
                    SELECT memberid,csdate,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid ORDER BY memberid,csdate) rowid
                    FROM test_transpose
                    )q
                    PIVOT
                    (MAX(csdate) FOR rowid IN ('+@PivotINColumnList+N'))pvt
                )q1
                JOIN
                (
                    SELECT  memberid,'
                +@Enddate_SelectColumnList
                +N'
                    FROM
                    (
                    SELECT memberid,cedate,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY memberid ORDER BY memberid,csdate) rowid
                    FROM test_transpose
                    )q
                    PIVOT
                    (MAX(cedate) FOR rowid IN ('+@PivotINColumnList+N'))pvt
                )q2
                ON q1.memberid = q2.memberid
                '
    PRINT @SQL
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a  version of Postgres db wise doing this work. Here is my sample of code.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS x;
CREATE TABLE x ( member NUMERIC , contract_start DATE, contract_end DATE);

INSERT INTO x VALUES( 1, '1/1/2011', '12/30/2011' )
,( 1, '1/1/2012', '12/30/2012' )
,( 1, '1/1/2013', '12/30/2013' )
,( 2, '7/1/2012', '12/30/2012' )
,( 2, '1/1/2013', '12/30/2013' )
,( 3, '1/1/2012', '12/30/2012' )
,( 3, '1/1/2013', '12/30/2013' )
,( 3, '8/1/2013', '12/30/2013' )
,( 3, '8/1/2013', '12/30/2013' );

-- CREATE LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
-- DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS seq;
-- CREATE SEQUENCE seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_table() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  i RECORD;
  colcnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable;
  SELECT max(count) INTO colcnt FROM (SELECT count(*) FROM x GROUP BY member) a;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE tmptable (member integer ,' || 
    (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(x1.col1 || ' date, ' || x1.col2 || ' date'), ', ')
      FROM (SELECT 'contract_start' || col col1
      , 'contract_end'|| col col2 FROM generate_series(1,colcnt) t(col) ) x1 ) || ')';

  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tmptable (member) SELECT DISTINCT member FROM x';

  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY member LOOP
    PERFORM setval('seq',1);
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmptable SET ' || x1.col 
      FROM (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(' contract_start' 
      || nextval('seq')-1 || ' = ''' || i.contract_start || ''', contract_end' 
      || currval('seq')-1 || ' = ''' || i.contract_end ), ''', ') || ''' WHERE member = ' || member || ';' col 
      FROM x WHERE member = i.member GROUP BY member) x1;
  END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM make_table();
SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```

This is the first time I am answering. Hope this is relevant. (please run the commented only once).

Further the process of calling function each time on insert, update or delete can be automated with trigger. The following code will do that on replace of above one.

```
-- following commented lines for first time run :
-- CREATE LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
-- DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS seq;
-- CREATE SEQUENCE seq;
-- DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS make_table();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION make_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  i RECORD;
  colcnt INTEGER;
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmptable;
  SELECT max(count) INTO colcnt FROM (SELECT count(*) FROM x GROUP BY member) a;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE tmptable (member integer ,' || 
    (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(x1.col1 || ' date, ' || x1.col2 || ' date'), ', ')
      FROM (SELECT 'contract_start' || col col1
      , 'contract_end'|| col col2 FROM generate_series(1,colcnt) t(col) ) x1 ) || ')';

  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO tmptable (member) SELECT DISTINCT member FROM x';

  FOR i IN SELECT * FROM x ORDER BY member LOOP
    PERFORM setval('seq',1);
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE tmptable SET ' || x1.col 
      FROM (SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(' contract_start' 
      || nextval('seq')-1 || ' = ''' || i.contract_start || ''', contract_end' 
      || currval('seq')-1 || ' = ''' || i.contract_end ), ''', ') || ''' WHERE member = ' || member || ';' col 
      FROM x WHERE member = i.member GROUP BY member) x1;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN new;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER create_tmptable AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE 
ON x FOR STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_table();

-- For Test insert:
INSERT INTO x VALUES( 4, '1/1/2011', '12/30/2011' );
SELECT * FROM tmptable;
```